# Python recursive file search

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I just started with my first Python script. now I am facing a problem, which seems to exceed my current skills.

**Goal:**
I want to get all *.md files stored under ./pages/. As I read the walk function from os seems to be the easiest way to get this goal.

**Problem:**
The result I get now is not correct. It seems to be in the right direction but something is not going the way it should. The if statement always results in the else clause and I really don't know why. In addition to that all .md files are found the if condition is never true.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import glob

def get_mds(): 
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./pages/"):
    for name in files:
      if name.endswith((".md")):
        print("success")
      else:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Here is the output from this script.

```
# Output
./pages/01.home/wizard.png
./pages/01.home/deploy-key.png
./pages/01.home/workflow.png
./pages/01.home/default.md <- MD
./pages/01.home/webhooks.png
./pages/01.home/01.how-to/default.md <- MD
```

As you can see all .md files were found. But it always end up in the else clause. What would be the right condition to match *.md files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working well, but maybe u misunderstood it. As you can see all *.md are located under `./pages/01.home` directory, however, your `files` list only has all files under `./pages'. Here is a simple modifing code to get all files under root path and the first sub-dir.

```
import os
import sys
import glob

def get_files(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        return files

def get_mds(path): 
    files_result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        files_result.extend(files)
        for dir in dirs:
            files_result.append(get_files(path+dir))

    for name in files_result:
        if name.endswith((".md")):
            print("success")
        else:
            print(os.path.join(root, name))

get_mds("./pages/")
```

Comment: the function already returns .md files in subfolder of the rootdir. Somehow with changeing ".md" to '.md'. So somehow it works. But your code makes as much sense or even more. Thanks for replying!

Comment: The explanation is bogus. `os.walk` traverses all directories in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./pages/"):
   for name in files:
     if name.endswith('.md'):
       print(os.path.join(root, name))
     else:
       continue
```

Output:

```
./pages/01.home/01.how-to/default.md
./pages/01.home/default.md
```

Replaced " with ' and everything works as expected

Comment: Single and double quotes are equivalent in Python, as long as you pair them correctly. I *think* the actual fix was when you dropped the extra parentheses around the argument to `endswith`.